# What happens when you create an object like this?

Tags: java, object, reference

[image]

So

`A a1=new A();` does the drawing on the left.

and

`B b1=new B();` does the drawing on the right.

What if I do this...

```
B c1=new A();
```

How would that fit in the drawing?

Also, another question.

```
A a1=new A();
```

I understand that "new A()" creates the A rectangle
and "a1" creates the a1 reference.

What does "A" at the beginning do? And where does it fit in this drawing?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you exactly asking about ? Are you talking about inheritance ?

Comment: The "A at the beginning" is the reference type of a1 -- it defines what sort of object reference the variable a1 can contain.  And note that `int i1 = 7;` is declaring a variable of type `int` (integer) that can contain a number (in this case 7).  This is NOT a "reference" to an object, but rather a "scalar" value.

Comment: Where is the drawing from? Is this a homework question?

Comment: (You probably should find a very basic Java tutorial somewhere and follow it.)

Answer (score 1):

`B c1 = new A()` is generally not correct unless A is a derived class from B. If it is - it will create an instance of `A` referenced by a variable named c1 (whose class type is B).

The A at the beginning specifies the type of the instance. It is often used in static analysis compilers to determine the operations available on the instance the variable is pointing to.
For example, if you write `int a` the compiler will know that variable a should be treated as an an integer and will warn/fail at compile time if you're trying to perform an operation not supported by `int` type.

Answer (score 1):

`class A` has to `extends` `class B` in order for you to be able to do `B c1 = new A();`

In order for you understand how the two interact, you need to understand inheritance and how the constructors interact.